# Getting App.nw location on OSX

Tags: node.js, macos, node-webkit

We're building a node-webkit/NW.js application for OS X and want to create a updater for the application so that it will be kept up-to-date automatically.

Because we deploy the nodeJS, css and html in a `App.nw` package. It's quite easy to download a new package and just replace the old one and restart the application. After searching somewhat on Google we couldn't find any way of getting the location of the `App.nw` package on OS X.

We deploy a node-webkit redist on OS X but we use our own CEF client for Windows. On Windows it's quite simple, you just get the `NW.exe` path and work your way to the `App.nw` from there. Is there some way of doing that on OS X?

Also it might be good to state that we're working on an older version of node-webkit, version 0.8.6. This is because a lot of native modules don't work on 0.9+ of node-webkit because they need NodeJS 0.10.

Answer (score 0):

While you are running your app your can do:

```js
var path = window.location.pathname;
path = path.substr(0, path.lastIndexOf('/'));
```

That will give your the full path to the app.nw.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is different depending upon whether you are working in a Terminal (command line) window or from Finder.

In OS X, the nw application is called *nwjs*.  You can look around inside the application bundle by right clicking on the application and selecting the *Show Package Contents* menu item.  Navigate to *Contents -> Resources* and you will see your *App.nw* file or directory there.

From the command line, go to the directory containing the *nwjs* app.  It should have the name, *nwjs.app*.  From that directory the file (or directory) that you want is *nwjs.app/Contents/Resources/App.nw*

When customizing your packaged application it is perfectly ok to rename *nwjs.app* to *your_app_name.app*.  So the name of the app might be something different from *nwjs.app*.

Comment: I'm trying to get the full path of the App.nw programmatically, from within NodeJS. How would opening it from Finder or from a terminal window make getting the location within NodeJS any different?

Comment: Ahh.  The original post didn't say you were trying to find the path programmatically.  I thought you were trying to find the location where the updated package should be installed in the application bundle.  (That location is not well documented.)   The nw.js javascript code appears to get the path of App.nw with a call to nw.callStaticMethod('App', 'GetPackage', [ ]).  I'm not sure if nw is a global but you might try this.  Unfortunately, if App.nw is a zip file you might end up getting the path to the unzipped version which must be in some temporary directory.